# Loading large data with reactfire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, reactfire

I'm using **REACTFIRE** to load a large amount of data (more than 1500 categories). This is how I bind my data as an array:

```
var ContentTable=React.createClass({
mixins: [ReactFireMixin],

getInitialState: function(){

    return{firebaseRefArray:[]};
},

componentWillMount: function() {

    //reference to firebase 
    var firebaseRef=firebaseAuthUtils.getRef();
    this.bindAsArray(firebaseRef.child("Categories"),"firebaseRefArray"); 

}, 
render:function(){

    return (<Table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th><th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>            
                    {this.state.firebaseRefArray.map(function(firebaseRef){
                        return (<tr> 
                                    <td> {firebaseRef[".key"]}</td> 
                                    <td> {firebaseRef.name}</td> 
                               </tr>
                               )
                    }.bind(this))}
                </tbody>
                </Table>);    
}
```

});

Unfortunately this takes a huuge amount of time and sometimes my app crashes.I want to know if there is a better way of doing this (without paginating). When I was using vanilla javascript I used the 'child-added' event to append the data  and it loaded at a reasonable amount of time. can I do something with similar effect with **REACTFIRE**??

**Edit:** 
So it seems react does not incrementally add data but does it all again and again until all the data is loaded. So is there a way around this?

Ive tried **shouldComponentUpdate** as shown below but it does not render at all. By logging I know that the array keeps growing but the comparison does not show them to be different at any two times. Its as though the **prevstat.firebaseRefArray** and current **state.firebaseRefArray** are growing at the same rate so the condition is always false.

```
shouldComponentUpdate:function(prevProps,prevState){
   return (this.state.firebaseRefArray!==prevState.firebaseRefArray)

},
```

Ive also tried the condition `this.state!==prevState` This is too slow and renders more than 1500 times (so far).
Does anyone have any suggestions please. Seems strange that React does not have a way to deal with this amount of data. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: If you need to download a lot of data to subsequently filter it down in your app, you should probably consider restructuring your data to not download it all anymore. The best way to do that depends on your data structure and your use-cases. I highly recommend reading this [article on NoSQL Data Modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) to learn about the common approaches.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for your comment. Primarily, I would like to be able to load all my 1000+ records without taking too long. As for the querying I have a few ideas. As I mentioned I have applied this in vanilla javascript and I was happy with the loading time, now I am using REACTFIRE and its not as fast.  I have reedited my question to focus on this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the data with a plain REST request, getting the data as JSON and then loading it into your array. This should be much faster, but won't provide two way binding.
See documentation for the [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html)

Comment: Yes that is the issue. I would like a way that allows two way biding. I  think the issue is that react keeps re-rendering. for approx 1500 records thats a lot. I've been doing some reading and seems some people have noticed this with react. I'm still not sure how to deal with it though